# How can I move vertex to a virtual line?

Tags: modeling

[image]

In the tutorial, it says you can press the G key and then the ALT key. It doesn't work.
I tried pressing C, but I can't. blender version is 2.90.1

Comment: could you please link the tutorial?

Comment: here you are  https://youtu.be/KzA5fOIq8Qw?t=718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

double g key and press c or press alt